# hook update_option/updated_option empty $old_value and $value

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I am trying to log each option update (later i will filter out the unnecessary ones). I have came across the 'update_option' and 'updated_option' hooks. They are triggering but the problem is that $old_value and $value are empty and/or not defined.

When I do not use default values for the $old_value and $value I get error that too few parameters was passed into the function. But according to WP documentation I should get both of them.

Any idea what´s wrong?

```
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('update_option', [$this, 'update']);
}

/**
 * @param $option string Name of the option to update
 * @param $old_value mixed Old option value
 * @param $value mixed New option value
 */
public function update($option, $old_value = "", $value = "")
{
    /** @var $current_user WP_User */
    global $current_user;

    if ($old_value || $value) {
        var_dump('old: ' . $old_value);
        var_dump('new: ' . $value);
        die;
    }

    if ($old_value == $value) {
        return;
    }

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: The syntax should be: `add_action('update_option', [$this, 'update'], 10, 3)` because your function is accepting 3 arguments.

Comment: Oh, how can I be so stupid. Thank you very much. If you will post it as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax should be: `add_action('update_option', [$this, 'update'], 10, 3)` because your function is accepting 3 arguments:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    add_action('update_option', [$this, 'update'], 10, 3);
}
```

PS: `add_action()`'s [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/).

Comment: Thank you again, you answer is now accepted.